# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseURL')

Tags: angular

**dailyplanningservice.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppConfigService } from 'src/app/services/config/app-config.service';

import { Observable,} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequisitionProposalPostModel } from '../model/requisition-proposal';
var jsonData = './assets/data/test.json';

interface JsonResponse {
  status: number;
  message: any;
  data: object;
  dataList:Array<any>;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DailyplanningService {


  private handleResponse(response: JsonResponse) {
    return response;
  }

  serviceBase = "";
  baseUrl = "";
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
    private configService: AppConfigService) {

    this.baseUrl = this.configService.getConfig().baseURL;
    this.serviceBase = this.configService.getConfig().serviceBase;
  }

  getReportData(imoCode: string) {
    return this._http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + this.serviceBase + `dailyplan/noonReport?imoCode=` + imoCode);
  }

  getVesselData(imoCode: string) {   
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + this.serviceBase + `dailyplan/vesselCard?imoCode=` + imoCode);
  }

  getVesselCardData(imoCode: any): Observable<Object> {
    return  this._http.get(this.baseUrl + this.serviceBase + `dailyplan/port?imoCode=` + imoCode)
  } 

  submitrfqProposal(requisitionProposalPostModel: RequisitionProposalPostModel): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post<any>( this.baseUrl + this.serviceBase + 'dailyplan/requisition', requisitionProposalPostModel);
  }

  getRequisitionProposal(imoCode:any, voyageId:any): Observable<any> {

    return this._http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + this.serviceBase + `dailyplan/requisitionproposal?imoCode=` + imoCode +"&voyagePassageId="+voyageId);

 


  }


  // public getVesselData1(imoCode: any) {
  //   return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + this.serviceBase + `dailyplan/vesselCard?imoCode=` + imoCode).pipe(
  //     catchError(
  //       (error: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>) => {
  //         console.error(
  //           'the component has caught an error, process it here',
  //           error
  //         );
  //         this.error = error;
  //         return of();
  //       }
  //     )
  //   );
  // }


  doRequest(endpointURL: string,
    method: string, data?: any,
    parms?: any, headers?: HttpHeaders) {

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers ? headers : new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: !data ? {} : JSON.stringify(data),
      parms: parms
    }

    return this._http
      .request<JsonResponse>(method, this.baseUrl + this.serviceBase + `${endpointURL}`, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map(response =>
          this.handleResponse(response))
      );


  }
}
```

**.ts file**

It seems that the default test case is not running because of the error cannot read properties of undefined. I tried to search that in .ts file but didn't find solution.
And not only for this component but for every component it is giving the same error. Atleast the default tests should have run.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CognitoService } from 'src/app/modules/auth/cognito.service';
import { DailyplanningService } from 'src/app/modules/pages/daily-planning/service/dailyplanning.service';
import { CommonService } from 'src/app/services/common/common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  responseLst: any = [];
  dailyplanningURL = "";
  bell_icon: boolean = false;

  constructor(public router: Router,
    private _service: DailyplanningService,
    private common: CommonService,
    public cognitoService: CognitoService) {

    this.common.shareDailyPlaningURL.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.dailyplanningURL = res;
    });


    this.common.shareVesselData.subscribe((res: any) => {
      if (res) {
        this.responseLst = res;
      } else {
        this.getVesselData();
      }

    });

  }

  userAdminUrlActive = "";
  loading: boolean = false;
  collapsed = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {
console.log();

  }

  
  toggleCollapsed(): void {
    this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
  }


  goDashboard() {
    this.dailyplanningURL = '';
    this.isShowPopIn = false;
    this.router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']);
  }

  changeUrl() {
    this.dailyplanningURL = '';
    this.isShowPopIn = false;
  }

  logout() {
    this.cognitoService.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
  userAccountClick() {
    this.userAdminUrlActive = '/pages/useraccount';
    this.router.navigate(['/pages/useraccount']);
  }
  vesselMgtClick() {
    this.userAdminUrlActive = '/pages/vesselmanagement';
    this.router.navigate(['/pages/vesselmanagement']);
  }


  gotoDailyplanning(data: any) {
    this.isShowPopIn = false;
    sessionStorage.setItem("vesselData", JSON.stringify(data));

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/dashboard')
      .then(() => this.router.navigate(['/pages/dailyplanning']));
    this.dailyplanningURL = '/pages/dailyplanning';
  }

  isShowPopIn = false;
  showdailyPlanning() {
    if (this.isShowPopIn) {
      this.isShowPopIn = false;
    } else {
      if (this.responseLst.length == 0) {
        this.getVesselData();
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isShowPopIn = true;
      }, 500);

    }
  }

  getVesselData() {
    try {
      this.loading = true;
      let apiURL = "useradmin/vessels?email=" + sessionStorage.getItem('email')
      this.common.doRequest(apiURL, 'get').subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          let result: any = res;
          this.responseLst = [];
          if (result) {
            if (result.status == 200) {
              result.dataList.forEach((item: any) => {
                let obj: any = new Object();
                Object.keys(item).forEach(function (key: string) {
                  if (item[key] == 0 || item[key] == null) {
                    obj[key] = "0";
                  } else {
                    obj[key] = item[key];
                  }

                });
                this.responseLst.push(obj);
                this.loading = false;
              });
            }
          }
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          this.loading = false;
          console.log('Error in getVesselData:' + error);
        }
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      this.loading = false;
      console.log('Error in getVesselData:' + error.message);
    }

  }


  
}
```

**spec.ts file**

```
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**error message**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseURL')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseURL')
    at new DailyplanningService (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/modules/pages/daily-planning/service/dailyplanning.service.ts:32:50)
    at Object.DailyplanningService_Factory [as factory] (ng:///DailyplanningService/ɵfac.js:4:10)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:256012:35)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:255831:33)
    at NgModuleRef.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:266387:33)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:266064:35)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:247913:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:248025:12)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:258951:12)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.HeaderComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:///HeaderComponent/ɵfac.js:4:81)
```

Comment: Seems like error is coming from `dailyplanning.service.ts`, you would have to mock `dailyplanning.service.ts` provider as well.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to add daily planning component  in providers like this beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
      providers: [DailyplanningService],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

Comment: Do you mind to add the `dailyplanning.service.ts` code? I can help to solve it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several dependencies invoked from your component.

```
HeaderComponent
      |  
      V
DailyplanningService
      |  
      V
AppConfigService
      |  
      V
?????????? (perhaps next dependencies)
```

So error is thrown from `AppConfigService` service after calling `this.configService.getConfig()` method from the `DailyplanningService` constructor.

That way you would have to mock `AppConfigService` instance from the providers array. Perhaps you have to mock more things, but from code, now I can only see the `getConfig` method has to be mocked.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
         {
            provide: AppConfigService,
            useValue: {
                getConfig: () => ({ 
                  baseUrl: 'dummy-url',
                  serviceBase: 'api-base'
                })
            }
         }
      ],
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
});
```